# Find old computers in AD is not accurate?

Tags: powershell

Playing around with the Get-EventLog command.    The first 3 commands work as expected.

```
Get-EventLog Application -Newest 1000 | Select Message
Get-EventLog System -Newest 1000 | Select Message
Get-EventLog Security -Newest 1000 | Select Message
```

But this does not work

```
Get-EventLog Setup -Newest 1000 | Select Message
```

and this does not work

```
Get-EventLog setup
```

How come?  There are WSUS errors in the Setup that we'd like to capture.

Comment: I think I found it:      Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable @{logname = ‘setup’; id = 3}

Comment: Yes, `Get-EventLog` can only read the classic event logs, and cannot filter them on the remote machine. `Get-WinEvent` is the newer cmdlet which can read all the eventlogs, and filter results before bringing them over the network.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry this is a bit long but I'm kind of fond of try/catch statements and over-communication.

```
#requires -Version 2.0
function RemoteEventLog([Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]$LogName, $MaxEvents,[Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]$computers, $LogPath)
{
  <#
  .SYNOPSIS
  Gather remote event logs by log name by computer names.

  .DESCRIPTION
  Specifiy a log name to narrow down the search. Provide as many computernames as needed.

  .PARAMETER maxevents
  -maxevents is all about how many events.

  .PARAMETER computers
  The array or list of comma separated computer names to run the script through.

  .PARAMETER LogPath
  -LogPath will let you decide the parent folder of the location to store the logs by computer name.

  .EXAMPLE
  RemoteEventLog -logname Application -maxevents 1000 -computers ('host1','host2','host3')
  This will loop through the computers and bring back the log for each computer.
#>

$computers = $computers -split (',')
try
{
  $testLogPath = Test-Path $LogPath
}
catch
{
  "Error was $_"
  $line0 = $_.InvocationInfo.ScriptLineNumber
  "Error was in Line $line0"
}
if(!($testLogPath))
{
  try
  {
    New-Item -Path $LogPath -ItemType Directory -ErrorAction:Stop
  }
  catch
  {
    "Error was $_"
    $line1 = $_.InvocationInfo.ScriptLineNumber
    "Error was in Line $line1"
  }
}

foreach($computer in $computers)
{ 
  try
  {
    $log = Get-WinEvent -LogName $logName -MaxEvents $maxevents -ComputerName $computer -ErrorAction:Stop
}
catch
{
  "Error was $_"
  $line2 = $_.InvocationInfo.ScriptLineNumber
  "Error was in Line $line2"
}

try
{
  New-Item -Path $LogPath -Name ("$computer.evt") -Value $log -Force
  $log | Out-File -FilePath $LogPath     
}
catch
{
  "Error was $_"
  $line3 = $_.InvocationInfo.ScriptLineNumber
  ('Error was in Line {0}' -f $line3)
  }
}
}

RemoteEventLog -logname Application -MaxEvents 100 -computers 'localhost,computer2,computer3' -LogPath D:\Desktop\logs
```